# Doesn't work flip animation for UIViewControllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, core-animation

I am trying create flip animation between `ViewController`'s but it doesn't work:

```
BHAppDelegate *app = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
UINavigationController *tabBarController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NavigationController"];

BHViewController *leftViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"leftMenu"];

PKRevealController *revealController = [PKRevealController revealControllerWithFrontViewController:tabBarController leftViewController:leftViewController];
[revealController setMinimumWidth:220 maximumWidth:220 forViewController:tabBarController];

[UIView beginAnimations:@"animation" context:nil];
    app.window.rootViewController = revealController;
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:self.navigationController.view cache:NO];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: "but it doesn't work". You're lucky to get an answer. Most people are allergic to this phrase without further explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry but why you are setting the `revealController` as `rootViewController` on the UIWindow?
I think that your code above is in your `rootViewController` and so from your rootViewController you should use this way to present the `revealController`:

```
    [revealController setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal];
    [self presentViewController:revealController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

and in the `revealController` you will use this way to dismiss and come back to the `rootViewController`:

```
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```